# PHP proxy to get cross domain xml and parse with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml

Since Google's feed load service was turned off, I'm struggling to find a new way to display xml feeds across different protocols and domains. I need to feed in a blog onto a website. The website is https, the blog is not. I have a some success here, <strike>but only in getting the title. I need to wrap the title in the link, and insert it into a li.</strike> Got that working, need to get it into DOM

Here is my proxy the path is (/SSI/Processor/feedProxy.php):

```
<?php
    function download_page($path){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}

$sXML = download_page('https://www.external.com/feeds/feed.xml');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

$items = $oXML->entry;
$i = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $title = $item->title;
    $link = $item->link;
    echo '<li>';
    foreach($link as $links) {
    $loc = $links['href'];
    echo "<a href=\"$loc\">";
}
echo $title;
echo "</a>";;
echo "</li>";
if(++$i == 3) break;
}
?>
```

### Edit

I can now get all the xml returned, and formatted via PHP. I just can't insert it into DOM with jQuery!

And my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:'/SSI/Processor/feedProxy.php',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);
        //console log is showing the formatted HTML
        $('#feeds').html(html);
    });
});
```

I am struggling with how to parse it in PHP. It needs to output like this: `<li><a href="linkfromxml">link text</a></li>` and append that to a div.

Comment: sorry, i misread it due to inconsistent formatting

Comment: not sure why you are asking form xml in ajax when you are really sending html

Comment: I apologize for the formatting. I have edited the question to ask for html

Comment: but your dataType is still xml.

Comment: That fixed it. I wish there was an easier way than using PHP cURL, I can't get the YQL version to work. Parsing JSON is much simpler.

Comment: Post an answer and I will accept if you are into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning html but you are setting the `dataType` to `xml`

Change it to `dataType:'html'`